# MKMapView error and SFViewController error

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I get an error whenever I try to use a mapview

"Use of undeclared type of MKMapView"

and "Use of undeclared type MKMapViewDelegate."

I also get the error when trying to call an SFSafariViewController.

For the first two, the code is

```
class pinViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addPinBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var linkTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
```

The safari view controller the code is

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.udacity.com/account/auth#!/signup")
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url as! URL)
        present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import` [`MapKit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit) framework to access Apple Map related class and [`Safari​Services`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices) framework to access `SFSafariViewController`. So simply add two `import` statement in your `pinViewController`

```
import MapKit
import Safari​Services
```

Remember one ting that batter if class name start with Capital latter, so simply change `pinViewController` to `PinViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Add these in your class

`import MapKit
 import Safari​Services`

If you still get the error.
   Open your project file
   Select your target
   Go to Build Phases
   Go to `Link Binary With Libraries`
   Tap on `+` and add `MapKit` and `SafariServices` upon searching.

Build and Run.